# How to get category wise post in my custom template page

Tags: wordpress

Here my is code. I want display related post in my custom page template. Now it will work fine only admin side. But when I was not logged in my account and also if logged in as a subscriber at that time it will not work perfectly. Here is my code please help me.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'psdupload',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID()),
                    'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID()),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',                    
                );               
                $loop = new WP_Query($args);

                //FOR CHECK IF POST ARRAY NULL OR NOT
                if($loop->have_posts())
                {
                    $loop = new WP_Query($args);                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $recent_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'psdupload',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        'orderby'        => 'date',
                        'order'          => 'DESC',
                        'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID()),
                        'post_status' => 'publish',                       
                    );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $recent_args );                    
                }
```

further, I will use "$loop" variable as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add follows code snippets -

```
global $post;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'     => 'psdupload', 
        'posts_per_page'=> 4,
        'category__in'  => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 
        'post__not_in'  => array($post->ID),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',  
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
    if( !$loop->have_posts() ) {
        $args = array( 
            'post_type'     => 'psdupload', 
            'posts_per_page'   => 4,
            'orderby'       => 'date',
            'order'         => 'DESC',
            'post__not_in'  => array($post->ID),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',  
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
    }

    if( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: how can I use "while loop" instead of "foreach loop"

Comment: @Parth I updated my codes as per your needs. Please check.

Comment: Thanks, bro...it will work fine. But a small bit of issue current post is also displayed on the user side.

Comment: You mean `post__not_in` not working, can you make sure that global `$post->ID` returning the current post id.

Comment: Yes, I will echo $post->ID. It will return current post id completely but I am so sad my dear bro....it will not work. if you have any other idea regarding this then please suggest me.

Comment: the above codes is tested and its work properly with `post__not_in` array id, means its properly excluded the post from loop. Can you please check this once by static giving a static post id within `post__not_in` array, just to be sure that post is coming or not.

Comment: Yes, bro.....i will check with static ID but the same issue is arriving. I mean how is it possible. IT works very perfectly when I was logged in as an admin but when I was logged in as user or without logging in "post__not_in " is not working.

Comment: It's tested with both user/admin logged in/out case. And I don't know the exact reason behind it in your end. May be your theme or some other plugins  overridden queries, I'm just guessing. So, you can test once with default theme and deactivated plugins which can may be a cause.

Comment: I think you are right. I will just check if any plugin overrides or not.